# Website theme change checklist

Tags: website-design, gui-design, color, font, themes

We are adapting the current UI to the new look, by `just changing the font/logo and some graphical images`.

Current Site Looks like

[image]

Basically, I  am trying to put all the changes in the document and submit it to the client for approval. As we dont have any prototypes provided by the client, we decided to design the document like below

The document contains the list of changes required.

1. Logo
2. Menu
3. Page Title
4. Page sub titles
5. Right side panel
6. Footer

Each section will contain the following information

Background Image, Image Size
Font - Type, Size, Color
Border

I would like to design this document in a professional way and present it. As I am not a UI/UX designer, I dont have any idea, how better I can put it together.

Are there any templates/checklists which would help to prepare it in a better looking way?

Answer (score 2):

If you are implementing a new look to a company, this is probably the best place to implement a style guide.

This will be a great start for defining the new identity and establishing a consistent tone of voice.

There is a mountain of resources out there for creating style guides, here are just a couple of useful links:

1. [Collection of style guides](http://www.creativebloq.com/branding/great-examples-design-style-guides-3132070)
2. [Designing Style Guides for Brands
   and Web Sites](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/21/designing-style-guidelines-for-brands-and-websites/)

There are many designers out there who specialise in this, and perhaps it would be extremely valuable to hire one for this project.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're just looking for a nice way of delivering a design spec. Creating a style guide is a great idea, but it significantly adds to your deliverable. You're going to spend a long time researching, choosing, and implementing a style guide, possibly only to find that it sits and gathers dust.

**If you're just looking for a way of delivering polished spec, check out http://www.specctr.com/**

They've got plugins for all the main Adobe apps, and for $49 you get a plugin that, once you've configured it, lets you annotate your docs with style references simply by clicking and dragging. I use it in fireworks and it works really well.

If this is something you're doing regularly, it's well worth a look. It brings consistency to your work, and, in an indirect way, it improves your design by pointing out the minor inconsistencies that often get missed.

Answer (score 0):

As Grant said, there are many designers and many design software's out there to choose from. I myself have used Yola and Wix webpage designers(Wix being the best for the job as you design in a HTML5 format). You can also use the online webpage designer/designee software 1&1. It will cost a bit but for that money you get a professional designer who is specially suited to what you are looking for.

So, if you are looking for a designer, 1&1 is the best choice. But if you want to design it yourself, use Wix. Hope this helps!

Comment: What do you mean by `1&1`?

Comment: @Billa 1&1 is an all-in-one domain registrar, webhost, site building, provider. They consistently get terrible reviews, specifically regarding their support. http://www.whoishostingthis.com/hosting-reviews/1and1/